# Solving Linearly Constrained Quadratic Programming with Coordinate Descent

Tags: convex-optimization, descent

Does anybody have any idea about how to solve the following problem with Coordinate Descent?
\begin{align}
\min &\quad \mathbf{x}^{\top}P\mathbf{x} + b^{\top}\mathbf{x}\\
\text{Subject to}& \quad A\mathbf{x} \leq c
\end{align}

I don't want to use the Bump Function technique and need the Coordinate Descent to be able to solve it in high dimensions.

Comment: I don't think you can solve the constrained problem directly using coordinate descent. For example, consider $\min \{ x^2+y^2 | x+y \geq 1 \}$. If you are at the feasible (but not optimal) point $(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4})$, then you cannot obtain a descent along the coordinates.

Comment: Finding gradient is not required. I searched more and found the following paper: C.-J. Hsieh, K.-W. Chang, C.-J. Lin, S. S. Keerthi, and S. Sundararajan, “A dual coordinate descent method for large-scale linear SVM,” in  ICML’08. What they do is to fix all but one variable and solve QP for the fixed variable which is certainly simple.

Comment: I understand the idea. But if you take the problem I described above, the point I mentioned is optimal in each coordinate if you take just one coordinate at a time. That is, the QP in either variable is already solved, but is non-optimal for the original problem (which is minimized at $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, of course).

Comment: The constraints in the paper are 'box' constraints, not a general constraint like $Ax \leq c$. Box constraints (ie, of the form $x_i \in [\underline{x}_i, \overline{x}_i]$) *are* amenable to coordinate-wise solution.

Comment: You are right! I experienced that problem with Coordinate Descent in another problem.

Comment: If we consider $min\{x^2+y^2\mid x+y\leq 1 , x\geq 0 , y\geq 0\}$, can we use the Coordinate Descent to get the answer $(0,0)$ from any starting point in the interior of feasible region?

Comment: The OP didn't specify if the problem is convex, i.e., is the matrix $P$ positive (semi-)definite?

Answer (score 2):

assuming $P$ to be positive semi-definite, your problem is simply a standard QP with linear constraints. Unless it shows some peculiarities in the linear constraints, the structure of $P$ or a huge dimension, I would just pick up any established QP solver (MOSEK, CPLEX, Gurobi...) or even just quadprog in MATLAB.

The papers you refer to deals to some specific situations:

- Tseng et al. considers non-smooth functions and this is not your case.
- Lin et al. is particularly focused on SVN application which are really huge problems. But in that case they solve the dual which a box-constrained QP which is somehow *easier*.

In general I would search for QP algorithms well before implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following paper answers my question to a great extent:

Tseng, Paul, and Sangwoon Yun. "A coordinate gradient descent method for nonsmooth separable minimization." *Mathematical Programming* 117.1-2 (2009): 387-423.